# Simplification of a boolean formula

Tags: logic

The following boolean formula is a tautology:

$(\lnot q \land p \Rightarrow q \land r) \land (\lnot (\lnot q \land p) \Rightarrow \lnot q \land  \lnot r) \Rightarrow \lnot p$

I figured it out using a truth table as I could not figure out how to solve it algebraically. Would anyone know whether it is always possible to prove that a boolean formula is a tautology algebraically (i.e. using just logical equivalences) and without using truth tables?

Comment: @BrianO what if the stock is just the basic commutative, associative, distributive, identity, negation, double negative, idempotent, De Morgan, absorbtion, conditional?

Comment: This depends on your stock of logical equivalences. But assuming you have enough of them, and the right ones, yes it is always possible. Propositional logic can be formalized in axiomatic systems with just a few axioms (schemas, really, as all substitution instances are taken as theorems), plus the inference rule Modus Ponens (MP). You can think of MP as an algebraic identity: $p \land (p\to q) \equiv q$. So, yes, all and only all theorems are derivable algebraically.

Comment: A fairly standard set, and yes they are sufficient. In the worst case, just eliminate $\to$ in favor of $\neg, \lor$, use De Morgan, absorption, etc to simplify, and hopefully arrive at a known tautology (e.g. $p\lor \neg p$). I'll try to answer.

Comment: @BrianO Would you be able show how to solve the formula in this post algebraically? I couldn't do it but I'm interested in seeing how it could be done. Thanks.

Comment: There. It gets pretty awful in the middle but then it settles down:)

Comment: @BrianO Thanks. I'm going to have to take some time to digest that...  8-)

Comment: Not surprisingly. Ideally, I'd highlight the subformula(s) that change from one line to the next... but then I'd still be doing that.

Comment: See the comment I added at the end, which should help you not get dizzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given
$$(\lnot q \land p \to q \land r) \land (\lnot (\lnot q \land p) \to \lnot q \land  \lnot r) \to \lnot p \tag{1}
$$
I'll reduce this to a tautology using the commutative, associative, distributive, identity, negation, double negative, idempotent, De Morgan, absorption [*one 'b', one 'p'*], and conditional rules & definitions.

First, get rid of $\to$. Note that 
$$(A\land B)\to C\equiv \neg(A\land B)\lor C\equiv (\neg A \lor \neg B) \lor C,\tag{Eq1} 
$$ 
by conditional and De Morgan, and that 
$$\neg(S\to T)\equiv (S\land \neg T) \tag{Eq2}
$$
by conditional, De Morgan and double negation elimination. Thus:
$$\begin{align}
(1)& \iff \neg(\lnot q \land p \to q \land r) \lor \neg(\lnot (\lnot q \land p) \to \lnot q \land  \lnot r) \lor \lnot p \tag{by Eq1} \\
& \iff (\lnot q \land p \land \neg(q \land r)) \lor (\lnot (\lnot q \land p) \land \neg(\lnot q \land  \lnot r)) \lor \lnot p \tag{by Eq2} \\
& \iff (\lnot q \land p \land (\neg q \lor \neg r)) \lor ((q \lor \neg p) \land (q \lor r)) \lor \lnot p \tag{De Morgan, $\neg\neg$} \\
& \iff (p\land (\lnot q \land (\neg q \lor \neg r))) \lor ((q \lor \neg p) \land (q \lor r)) \lor \lnot p \tag{commut., assoc.} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor ((q \lor \neg p) \land (q \lor r)) \lor \lnot p \tag{absorption} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor (((q \lor \neg p) \land q) \lor ((q \lor \neg p)\land r)) \lor \lnot p \tag{distributivity} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor (q \lor ((q \lor \neg p)\land r)) \lor \lnot p \tag{absorption} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor (q \lor ((q \land r) \lor (\neg p\land r))) \lor \lnot p \tag{distributivity} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor q \lor (q \land r) \lor (\neg p\land r) \lor \lnot p \tag{associativity} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor q \lor (\neg p\land r) \lor \lnot p \tag{absorption} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor q \lor \lnot p \tag{absorption} \\
& \iff (p\land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \lor q)\tag{assoc., commut.} \\
& \iff \neg(p\land \lnot q) \to (\lnot p \lor q)\tag{conditional} \\
& \iff (\neg p\lor q) \to (\lnot p \lor q)\tag{De Morgan, $\neg\neg$} \\
\end{align}
$$
This last formula is of course a tautology.

After the 5th equivalence [the first one that's tagged (absorption)], $(p\land \neg q)$ remains unchanged till the very end, and all the transformations are to subformulas after the first $\lor$. Also, the final $\lor \neg p$ doesn't come into play until after 5th to last equivalence: in the 4th to last equivalence, the final $(\neg p\land r) \lor \lnot p$ becomes $\neg p$ by absorption. So in the middle, all the action is between the leftmost and rightmost $\lor$s.

Answer (score 1):

1. $(\neg q \wedge p \to q \wedge r)\wedge (\neg (\neg q\wedge p)\to\neg q\wedge\neg r)$
2. suppose $p$
3. suppose $q$

$\neg q\wedge p$ is false.

Therefore, $\neg (\neg q\wedge p)$ is true.

$\neg q\wedge \neg r$ is false.

Therefore, $\neg (\neg q\wedge p)\to\neg q\wedge \neg r$ is false.

Therefore, if we assume $q$ then (1.) is false.

4. suppose $\neg q$

$\neg q\wedge p$ is true.

$q\wedge r$ is false.

Therefore, $\neg q\wedge p\to q\wedge r$ is false.

Therefore, if we assume $\neg q$ then (1.) is false.

5. It follows that $\neg p$ must be true since regardless of whether $q$ is true or not, letting $p$ be true always resulted in (1.) being false.

Thus we proved $\neg p$ from (1.), which makes (1.)$\to \neg p$ a tautology.

All of the steps I used in this proof are consistent with classical first order logic. If you get stuck at any particular spot I can let you know the names of which rules were used.

Comment: yes, your proof works. But when I meant algebraically, I meant you can use steps 2 and 3 which are truth assignments. You can use only logical equivalences in your proof. Nice try, though... 8-)

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you're asking for. There's a neat trick in classical first order logic that every operator can be expressed using only $\neg$ and $\wedge$. One would expand the expression and then contract it cancelling $\neg$'s, eliminating accepted tautologies, and copious applications of de Morgans laws. Good luck to @BrianO